# Textures Reorganize When I Unwrap

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm having a big problem here.
I've applied different textures to the faces of my model and it looks exactly how I want it to, until I unwrap it.

Pre-Unwrap:

[image]

Post-Unwrap:

[image]

And now I can't bake the texture.

What should I do? Why is this happening? Can I not bake the texture exactly as it appears in the viewport?:-(

Comment: Have you not already unwrapped in order to draw all these details?

Comment: @moonboots I unwrapped it in parts. For instance, I unwrapped the face in order to bring it into Photoshop and design it. Then I unwrapped the vest and did something similar. I actually have a bigger project that I'm working on-- it's a big mansion, and I add textures as I build more of the model. I'm not even done building it yet and I already have like 100 textures. At the end I was going to join all the walls, doors, chairs, etc into one mesh and bake it. I'm very scared the texture is going to jump around like it did here.

Comment: but if you have already unwrapped it, why are you unwrapping it again? If you need to unwrap some parts, at least don't unwrap again the parts you've already unwrapped, otherwise they will be lost...

Comment: @moonboots Ohhh. I see what you're saying. I selected everything and was trying to unwrap everything together, because that's how the YouTube tutorials were showing how to do it. You're saying that I should unwrap everything that hasn't previously been unwrapped (like the face and vest), and then I can bake. I'm gonna try it! I will report back. Thank you!

Comment: @moonboots Okay, I think I've almost got it, but there's still a problem. I went ahead and unwrapped everything separately-- the pants, the shirt, the shoes, the hair, and the skin. So now everything is unwrapped to its own UV map. Then I baked. Oddly everything with an image texture (face, vest, and pants) went crazy and now is a jumble of colors (not sure how to attach an image to this comment). Everything with a plain flat color is fine. Please note that all image textures were applied using the materials tab and not with nodes. My goal is just to have one texture for the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I have solved the problem after several days of pulling my hair out. Shoutout to @moonboots for setting me on the right track. First of all, [THIS YOUTUBE VIDEO](https://youtu.be/9airvjDaVh4) will explain mostly everything. A couple things it won't explain:

- You cannot have both image textures and flat color textures in the same model. I, for instance, used image texture for the clothes and flat color for the skin, hair and boots. What you must do is import your flat colors as images and have blender pull from those. I myself made a texture palette with all the main colors I will use. [THIS](https://youtu.be/bP_1XfpEy80) is a good YouTube video showing how to do that.
  [image: ColorPaletteExample]
- You absolutely MUST use Nodes. I was intimidated by the Node Editor and found it so confusing that I kept strictly to the Materials Tab. No way, Jose. There's no getting around it; you have to use Nodes.
- If you are really stuck, OUTSOURCE. I hired someone on Fiverr.com to bake the model for me and make a list of steps to take so I would know how to do it myself. If you're going crazy, delegate!

Good luck guys!